# How to reset VisibilityTimeout for entire input AWS SQS queue if golang application is shutdown?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs

My golang-application uses `aws-sdk-go` to interact with an input queue. One message from the queue is processed about 7-10 min by a goroutine and then deleted. I would like to hide the message in the input queue setting `VisibilityTimeout` to 10min because another goroutines should not process the same message in this time interval.

There are risks that I can get when app is shut down and its context is cancelled:

1. If I do not reset `VisibilityTimeout` of a message somehow, I need to wait for it for 10min when app is restarted
2. If context is canceled (app is shutting down), I can't invoke `ChangeMessageVisibilityWithContext` to reset `VisibilityTimeout` to `0` when app is shut down, because cancelled context prevents this and the invocation will fail with error. I can create new context for this case but this is not good idea for some reasons

How do I reset `VisibilityTimeout` for the input queue when app is restarted?

Comment: "I can't invoke ChangeMessageVisibilityWithContext to reset VisibilityTimeout to 0"
You can use ChangeMessageVisisbility instead and don't pass it a context.

Comment: @DanielFarrell but how do I know this request is completed if I don't use context. But sounds reasonable

Comment: Context doesn't guarantee a request is completed.  It's more commonly used as a mechanism to broadcast cancellation